# jscodeshift to convert all named imports to default import MUI V5

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jscodeshift, codemod

Can somebody help with a jscodeshift to convert all the named imports to default import for MUI V5 (React + Typescript)
Current code

```
import { Button, TextField } from '@mui/material';
```

Expected output

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I whipped this up using Codemod Studio ([codemod share link](https://go.intuita.io/4DV544)):

> The link simply shows the codemod I placed below. Feel free to access it in the studio if you want to test or edit the codemod.

This should do what you are looking for.

I haven't tested it outside of codemod studio, so make sure you do so. To easily deploy it, you can export it to Intuita VS Code Extension in the top right corner ([as shown here @2:06](https://youtu.be/4_YeKGlnM8o?si=I6yQyiXQvE1qdij5&t=126)).

You can also run the codemod using jscodeshift cli as usual, but I find the extension to be easier for me.

```
import type { FileInfo, API, Options } from 'jscodeshift';
export default function transform(
    file: FileInfo,
    api: API,
    options: Options,
): string | undefined {
    const j = api.jscodeshift;
    const root = j(file.source);

    // Find all ImportDeclaration nodes
    root.find(j.ImportDeclaration).forEach(path => {
        // Ensure the import source is '@mui/material'
        if (path.node.source.value === '@mui/material') {
            // Ensure the import specifiers are ImportSpecifier nodes
            if (path.node.specifiers.every(specifier => specifier.type === 'ImportSpecifier')) {
                // Create new ImportDeclaration nodes for each ImportSpecifier
                const newImports = path.node.specifiers.map(specifier => {
                    // Ensure the imported element is an Identifier
                    if (specifier.imported.type === 'Identifier') {
                        // Create a new ImportDeclaration node
                        return j.importDeclaration(
                            [j.importDefaultSpecifier(j.identifier(specifier.imported.name))],
                            j.literal(`@mui/material/${specifier.imported.name}`)
                        );
                    }
                });

                // Replace the original ImportDeclaration node with the new ones
                path.replace(...newImports);
            }
        }
    });

    return root.toSource();
}
```

By looking at the exported code, the codemod simply looks for the `@mui/material` import source and replaces it with the imports you need.

You can create and debug simple codemods like this using Codemod Studio. [See here](https://docs.intuita.io/docs/codemod-studio/quickstart) how to create your own codemods. Also, you can create them natively using jscodeshift API, but I find this method to be easier.

> You can simply insert the before code snippet in the 'Before' pane, the after code snippet in the 'After' pane, run ModGPT, and test/debug the returned codemod.

Disclosure: I'm affiliated with Intuita. By no means this is self-promotion. This is how I create codemods for simple use cases like this. Not all codemods can be made with Codemod Studio at the current time, but it can go a long way for simple changes and refactors like this.